# Is a whiteboard anachronistic in Ashes to Ashes?

Tags: props, historical-accuracy, ashes-to-ashes

In Series 1 Episode 1 of Ashes to Ashes, DI Alex Drake employs a whiteboard as she reasons out her situation with Shaz and Chris. Were whiteboards in general use in 1981? Is this an anachronism?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's certainly not an anachronism, although they weren't in very wide use.

Their creation can be placed [sometime in the late 1950s](http://www.theworkplacedepot.co.uk/news/2014/08/20/whiteboards-history/), although the first *dry* erasable marker wasn't invented until 1975.

So they were certainly around in 1981.

Comment: You might want to specify **dry** erase markers weren't available until '75 ;)

Comment: "During his work with film, he realized that notes could be recorded on film negatives using a marker pen and could be easily wiped off with a damp tissue".  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_pen (marker pen information)

Comment: @Catija: Definitely makes more sense with that in. Thanks

Comment: :D  Yeah, I read it and was like... what did they use for 15 years before erasable markers?... did they just throw them out every day? :P

Comment: I think some liquid cleaning chemical was used to clear the whiteboards.

Comment: Mind you, I still thought their stylish whiteboard-on-wheels looked rather present-day.